# SW6.5 App Administration extend Javascript, not shown

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

I'm moving over from Plugin to App development. I have the main.js in the Resources/app/administration/src
folder pointing to import './module/sw-product/page/sw-product-list-override';

my changes in the index.js file there:

import template from './sw-product-list.html.twig';

const { Component } = Shopware;
const { Criteria } = Shopware.Data;

Component.override('sw-product-list', {
template,  ..............

the twig file and it's content...

the old minified js file in Resources/public/administration/js

I tried build-administration.sh but the plugin lack the extension I'd like to display in the product list, it is like the Javascript is not included somehow, what changed from Plugin to App system, so that the app is not working with Javascript changes like that

Answer (score 3):

You can't introduce/extend/override components in the administration with apps as you did with plugins. You have to use the [`admin-extension-sdk`](https://shopware.github.io/admin-extension-sdk/docs/guide) and
the [admin custom modules](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/administration/add-custom-modules) schema of apps.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, I will have a look into it, thank you for now.